# How can I click on elements in a popup in notion.so using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, ui-automation

I am trying to automate an export process for [notion.so](https://www.notion.so/). I am a complete novice in puppeteer and ui-automation frameworks in general so any help is appreciated.
In the following pop-up I want to click on "current view" make a choice there and then click on "export"

[image: export popup]

This is what I have tried so far.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless :false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Set screen size
  await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});

  await page.goto('https://www.notion.so/');

  await page.waitForSelector('text/Log in');
  await page.click('text/Log in');

  const emailInput = await page.waitForSelector('#notion-email-input-1');
  await emailInput.type("mymail");
  await page.click('text/Continue with email');

  await page.waitForSelector('#notion-password-input-2');
  await page.type('#notion-password-input-2', 'mypass');
  const passwordButton = await page.waitForSelector('text/Continue with password');
  await passwordButton.click();

  const moreButton = await page.waitForSelector('div.notion-topbar-more-button');
  await moreButton.click();

  const exportButton = await page.waitForSelector('text/Export');
  await exportButton.click();

//  this works well untill this point
// beyond this point it seems like I can't interact with the elemens in the popup

//Below are some attempts to get the elements using XPath or other methods. None of them work.
  const databaseListView = await 
page.waitForXPath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]');
  await databaseListView.click();

  const everythingOption = await page.waitForSelector('#id_86>div>div>div');
  await everythingOption.click();

  const finalExportButton = await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="notion- 
app"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]');
  await finalExportButton.click();
  await delay(15000);

  await browser.close();
})();

function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
      setTimeout(resolve, time)
  });
}
```

What can I do to interact with these elements?

Comment: It's hard to help since the page is behind a login. In general, I would [avoid browser-generated selectors](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors), although that's probably not the issue. Are the clicks executing but doing nothing? If so, maybe try `await yourElement.evaluate(el => el.click())` to issue an untrusted event. If the waits are throwing, then look for iframes, shadow roots and so on.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the advice. How can I check if the clicks are executing on not?

Comment: Look at the page and see if the action you expect to happen happened after clicking the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below with updated locators, i was able to click on elements with below script, just updated the locators for popup

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const path = require('path');

    (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Set screen size
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });

    await page.goto('https://www.notion.so/');

    await page.waitForSelector('text/Log in');
    await page.click('text/Log in');

    const emailInput = await page.waitForSelector('#notion-email-input-1');
    await emailInput.type("user");
    await page.click('text/Continue with email');

    await page.waitForSelector('#notion-password-input-2');
    await page.type('#notion-password-input-2', 'pass');
    const passwordButton = await page.waitForSelector('text/Continue with password');
    await passwordButton.click();

    const moreButton = await page.waitForSelector('div.notion-topbar-more-button');
    await moreButton.click();

    const exportButton = await page.waitForSelector('text/Export');
    await exportButton.click();

    //  this works well untill this point
    // beyond this point it seems like I can't interact with the elemens in the popup

    //Below are some attempts to get the elements using XPath or other methods. None of them work.
    const databaseListView = await
        page.waitForXPath('//div[normalize-space()=\'Current view\']');
    await databaseListView.click();

    const everythingOption = await page.waitForXPath('(//div[normalize-space()="Everything"])[2]');
    await everythingOption.click();

   
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const finalExportButton = document.evaluate('//div[@role="button" and text()="Export"]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
        finalExportButton.click();
      });
    await delay(15000);

    await browser.close();
})();

function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, time)
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Indeed this does select the everything option. But the export button still doesn't get clicked for me

Comment: try the updated code, clicking on the Export button using the evaluate method instead of the click method. With the evaluate method in Puppeteer JS, you can execute JavaScript code within the context of a web page and manipulate the Document Object Model (DOM) of the page.